# Yii2 find query using mongodb

Tags: mongodb, yii2

I want to use query something like :

```
Select * from company where id is not null order by id desc
```

I am using YII2 framework with mongodb:

```
$company = Company::find()->where(['id' => null])->all();
```

The above query works fine for me but i want to use NOT NULL condition with order by. How can i do this ?

Answer (score 0):

Try 
`$company = Company::find()->where(['not', ['id' => null]])->orderBy('id desc')->all();`

Comment: It gives me a error message : not requires two operands

Comment: Hmm strange... Can You tell me in which file and line this error is thrown? Maybe You've got different Yii version than me. Try `->where(['not', 'id', null])`

Comment: "name": "Exception",
  "message": "Operator 'NOT' requires two operands.",
  "code": 0,
  "type": "yii\base\InvalidParamException",
  "file": "/local/project/vendor/yiisoft/yii2-mongodb/Collection.php",
  "line": 906,

Comment: I am trying : $Company = Company::find()->where(['not', ['id' => null]])->all();

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Comment: And `->where(['not', 'id', null])` returns error too?

Answer (score 0):

```
$company = (new Query)->from('company')->where(['NOT IN','_id',NULL])->all();
```